# Resetting Image to empty when clicking upload after already setting a photo

Tags: javascript, html

I have a segment of code that allows for an image to be seen when uploaded but not submitted. However I found that when you hit the upload again and cancel the upload/onchange the image will stay but is actual no longer saved to submit. I wanted it so that when you click upload it sets the element with nothing inside each time and when the upload/onchange is completed the image appear. However it just overrides it and makes it so nothing can be seen

```
// code for loading photo
var image = document.getElementById('output1');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

This is the code to clear the element
I had the element ID set to img.output or output1 I have been going back and forth trying to manipulate it but nothing changes both stop the image from showing now

```
function Empty(elementID){
    document.getElementById(elementID).src = "#";
}
```

This is the element that I wanted to manipulate thats should add the image but always clear when the button is clicked and allow upload when open from the file loader is done.

```
<p id ="output1"><img id="output" width="200" /></p>
```

So I am unsure if maybe I am clearing the whole  element and that is why it's completely deleting or if its taking precedence on the onclick vs the onchange that happens when you hit open for the upload. I would like more of an explanation of what could be going on with it since I know individually they all work fine but together they interfere.

EDIT:
Someone asked for the full code, there is quite a bit so I posted the sections that involve this part, some of the code is connected to a python file for picture upload which does not need to be changed and works fine even when the image is not seen

forgot to mention using django so that's where the csrf token comes from

```
<p id ="output1"><img id="output" width="200" /></p>
                    
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <!--Upload Image to media file-->
                        {%csrf_token%}
                        <a><input type="file" style="display: none;" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg" name="image" id="file" onchange="loadFile(event)" required/></a>
                        <button onclick = "Empty('img.output')" type="button" style="width: 100px; height: 30px; background-color: #008db1; border-radius: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px;"><label for="file"  style="cursor: pointer;">Upload Image</label></button>
                        <!--Only allow png or jpeg files, so far browse only-->
                        <button type="BrowseComputer" style="cursor: pointer; width: 100px; height: 30px; background-color: #008db1; border-radius: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px;">Submit</button>
                    </form>


<script>
                // add a reset to image on upload click & move it 
                function Empty(elementID){
                    document.getElementById(elementID).src = "#";
                 }

                var loadFile = function(event) {
                   
                var image = document.getElementById('output1');
                image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                 }

             </script>
```

Comment: could you please post the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having two errors in your code.

Firstly, when you call the `Empty()` function, you have set its elementID parameter to `img.output`, which is not an id. So, you need to change it from `img.output` to `output` only.

Secondly, you had used the following code in your JavaScript:

```
var image = document.getElementById('output1');
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
```

Here, you are trying to set the src of the element with `id = output`. In your HTML, the output1 is actually the `<p>` element. So, you are trying to set the src of a paragraph! So, change it from

```
var image = document.getElementById('output1');
```

to

```
var image = document.getElementById('output');
```

The finalized snippet is attached below:

```js
function Empty(elementID) {
  document.getElementById(elementID).src = "#";
}

var loadFile = function(event) {

  var image = document.getElementById('output');
  image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

```css
.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #008db1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p id="output1"><img id="output" width="200" /></p>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!--Upload Image to media file-->

  {%csrf_token%}

  <a><input type="file" style="display: none;" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg" name="image" id="file" onchange="loadFile(event)" required/></a>

  <button onclick="Empty('output')" type="button" class="btn"><label for="file" style="cursor: pointer;">Upload Image</label></button>

  <!--Only allow png or jpeg files, so far browse only-->

  <button type="BrowseComputer" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So I noticed something and I was wondering if you would also know how to fix this. Since the show image is based on an onchange if you were to go to upload and try the same image again it won't show up because its not technically a change, is there a way to reset that as well? Is there a better option then onchange?